# Shutdown option is not working in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, root, acer

I done my below option in my netbook **Acer Aspire One D260** netbook version.

1. I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 11.10 to 12.04. Unfortunately it was stopped due to my internet disconnect.
2. I tired to kill all the process using system monitor tool (select all process and press end process).

After above all those action my system not responding whenever I tried to shut down or log out.
I tried in terminal window using `shutdown -h now` command, but it tells that ***need to be root***.
But hibernate and suspend options are working fine.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `sudo shutdown -h now` instead of `shutdown -h now` to execute the command as root.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it, you must to edit `grub` file as follow: Type in terminal:

1. Type in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal): `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
3. Change this to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
4. Save and close the file.
5. Finally, in terminal: `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Dear friends, tried above steps but i got reply as" command not found". is any other possibility of solution there?

Comment: @Ramanathan94 Which command?

Comment: i tried with this commends in terminal window"sudo gedit /etc/default/grub". i got an answer as " command not found"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `sudo` to execute the command as root:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I tried "sudo shutdown -h now" comments. i am getting no comments found answer in terminal window

Comment: Hi All,now my netbook responding the comments "sudo shutdown -h now".i can able to shutdown my system.But how long should I use this comments. every time use this comments is not fair for Ubuntu. is any permanent solution there to rectify this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not fair for Ubuntu?". This is the proper way to shut down an Ubuntu system via command line.

Comment: i mean to say is, usually i shunting down using "shutdown" command from power menu. now every time i am using terminal window. I feel its tedious. do u knew how to rectify this issue

Comment: So the shutdown option is not working at all anymore, even after reboot? If so you should ask a new question instead of discussing this in the comments.

Comment: its okay Boss! please look on my question above and kindly let me know the solution. thanks in advance!